# Problem in Pycharm installation

Tags: pycharm

I used terminal window to install IntelliJ at first, which happened without disruption.When I tried for Pycharm instead, it didn't happen. Further I tried it with Ubuntu Software center, and it showed me this message:

> Unable to install pycharm CE: snap "pycharm-community" has install-snap change in progress.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue, follow this

```
-- install snap
command: sudo apt install snapd

-- install pycharm
command: sudo snap install pycharm-educational --classic
```

Once done you'll need to add `/snap/bin` in the PATH environment variable. (I'll let you know how once i figure it out)

Once done your command to launch pycharm would be `pycharm-educational`.